# Timer Flickers When It Reaches 0

Tags: java, timer, flicker

importing libraries

```
public class Countdown1 extends Applet implements Runnable {
// getting user input

    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter seconds: ");
 // converting string to integer

    int counter = Integer.parseInt(input);

    Thread countdown;

    public void start() {
        countdown = new Thread(this);
        countdown.start();

    }

// executed by thread
    public void run() {

        Timer timer;

        timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() /* counting down time inputted */ {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if (counter > 0) {

                    counter--;
// repainting each second

                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });
// timer started 

        timer.start();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
//painting text and time 

        g.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 35));
        g.drawString("Seconds: " + String.valueOf(counter), 260, 210);
        setBackground(Color.orange);
        setForeground(Color.magenta);

// change background to cyan when timer reaches 0
        if (counter == 0) {
            setBackground(Color.cyan);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't your `Timer` (although I do question the need to start it within a separate thread), the problem is with overriding `paint`.

Top level containers like `Applet` are not double buffered, meaning that the each paint action tends to be sent to the underlying `Graphics` device desperately.

Now you can over come this by employee some double buffering process OR you could...

- Extend from `JApplet` instead
- Create a custom component extending from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method instead, moving your custom painting to this method
- Add this component to the applet instead.

It should solve the immediate issue...

You should also avoid calling `setForeground` or `setBackground` from within any `paint` method.  In fact, you should avoid calling any method that might call `repaint` from within any `paint` method...

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

I'm pretty sure that `String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter seconds: ");` this is a bad idea.  Instead, you should provide some kind of control or option within the UI to change this value...

**Crude example**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Countdown1 extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        add(new CounterPane());
    }

    public class CounterPane extends JPanel {

        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter seconds: ");

        int counter = Integer.parseInt(input);

        public CounterPane() {

            Timer timer;

            timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() /* counting down time inputted */ {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println(counter);
                    if (counter > 0) {

                        counter--;

                        setBackground(Color.orange);
                        setForeground(Color.magenta);

                        if (counter <= 0) {
                            setBackground(Color.cyan);
                        }

                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            });

            timer.start();

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 35));
            g.setColor(getForeground());
            g.drawString("Seconds: " + String.valueOf(counter), 260, 210);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hope it helps you on your way ;)

Comment: This is quite delayed, but when I extend from JApplet the rather than Applet, my background colour turns back to white and the timer is repainting on top of the previous number.

Comment: I get an error that says "cannot find symbol method paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)"

Comment: That's because in your example you're overriding `paint`, which I did suggest not doing.  `JApplet` does not have a `paintComponent` method.  Instead, you should create a custom component extending from `JPanel` and place all your custom painting in it and then add it to the applet

Comment: I think I need to walk before running. I recently started Java and my knowledge of it is limited to what is before you. I don't understand what you meant at all. I greatly value your help though.

Comment: I added a crude example

Comment: Welcome to my world. My 2 year old makes me feel like an idiot on a regular bases...:P

Comment: I hear you. oh, what was the purpose of // g.setColor(getForeground());? and any idea why the counter has grey blackground and then switches after a second?

Comment: `g.setColor(getForegound())` changes the drawing color to be the same as the panels foreground color.  The reason for the switch is the fact that it takes a second for the timer to run, so you have the default color.  You could set the initial color in the panels constructor instead...(I did it in the timer as I was just cutting/pasting code)